# Test and production environments on Amazon AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm starting to develop a large-scale app using `node.js` and `DynamoDB`. I use Git and will possibly use a CI server.

I need a test environment (server side) that is as close as possible to the production envirinment. The changes I make to the DB while testing should not reflect in production. What's the best way to achieve it? Have a copy of the database for tests? How sould I implement a test environment when my app runs in Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

Never, ever, do development or testing on a production environment. Always make a copy of the environment for the purposes of testing and development.

Elastic Beanstalk allows you to create multiple copies of your application. So it's easy to spin up a second (or third, or fourth) copy of your application to do development and perform tests.

Once you're happy with the changes done in development, then apply those changes to your production environment in a controlled way. Hopefully your changes are reversible in case of a problem during deployment.

Comment: Ok, I understand how to replicate my application instance to perform tests, but what about DynamoDB? I want to test the application with an updated copy of the DB, but I don't want make changes in the production DB while testing. Is there a solution for it? I've read about cross-region replication but I'm afraid that it would be too expensive.

Comment: There's nothing out-of-the-box. You'd have to duplicate the tables (within the region using alternate names, or to another region, or to another account) and copy the data. Or you could use Lambda events to duplicate data written to your production table automatically to a dev table.

Answer (score 0):

Elastic Beanstalk allows you to easily manage multiple environments within an application. See [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.html) for more info.

As for DynamoDB, you'd have to come up with your own solution. One way that could work is if you manage your DynamoDB tables with [CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/) templates. This will allow you to define your tables, Primary Keys, any indexes within JSON template files. If you do it this way, you will have:

- CloudFormation templates in JSON which define and automatically create your DynamoDB tables.
- You can keep copies of these templates in a git repository where you can have a branch per environment, thus making it easier to manage your environments.

If this sounds too complicated, an easier apprach would be to just have copies of your tables with a "dev-" prefix or somthing similar within DynamoDB, however CloudFormation can come in really handy when you have many tables.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that you want an environment that is as close to production as possible, but I'm going to suggest you check out DynamoDB Local in case you haven't heard of it. Here is a link to the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html

It allows you to have a local version of DynamoDB. That means you can test without using read/write units. There are some differences between it and the production DynamoDB service, but you can do most of your test cases on the local version.